# UI Router Extras breaks my unit tests with unexpected results error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router, karma-runner

### **QUESTION:**

**- Why are my tests failing when ui-router-extras (not normal ui-router) is install?**

**- How can I use `ui-router-extras` and still have my tests pass?**

---

*If you want to install this quickly use yeoman + angular-fullstack-generator + bower install ui-router-extras*

[I found a similar issue with normal ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/212).

- Luckially, ui-router normal works just fine with my testing.
- After installing [ui-router-extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home) I get an **ERROR**

[image: Error log]

If I uninstall ui-router.extras it this test passes just fine:
[image]

**UPDATED for beforeEach module of $urlRouterProvider TEST**
Heres my test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('morningharwoodApp'));
  beforeEach(module('socketMock'));

  var MainCtrl,
      scope,
      $httpBackend;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope


  beforeEach(
    inject( function (_$httpBackend_, $controller, $rootScope) {
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/things')
        .respond(['HTML5 Boilerplate', 'AngularJS', 'Karma', 'Express']);

      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
      });
    }),
    module(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function(){ return false; });
    })
  );



  it('should attach a list of things to the scope', function () {
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

Here's my `karma.conf`

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'client/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'client/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'client/bower_components/famous-polyfills/classList.js',
      'client/bower_components/famous-polyfills/functionPrototypeBind.js',
      'client/bower_components/famous-polyfills/requestAnimationFrame.js',
      'client/bower_components/famous/dist/famous-global.js',
      'client/bower_components/famous-angular/dist/famous-angular.js',
      'client/app/app.js',
      'client/app/app.coffee',
      'client/app/**/*.js',
      'client/app/**/*.coffee',
      'client/components/**/*.js',
      'client/components/**/*.coffee',
      'client/app/**/*.jade',
      'client/components/**/*.jade',
      'client/app/**/*.html',
      'client/components/**/*.html'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.jade': 'ng-jade2js',
      '**/*.html': 'html2js',
      '**/*.coffee': 'coffee',
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'client/'
    },

    ngJade2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'client/'
    },

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: I find it is easier to test controllers, services, directives, etc...  If they are in modules with as few dependencies as possible. If it is possible create a root module that you bring your uirouter and uirouterExtras into. You can then remove the dependency from the module that contains the controller you are trying to test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might be a result of some component having a dependency on `$state` in which case `$state` will be instantiated and default route will be executed. This is why a template of one of your controllers `main.html` is being fetched.

To bypass this, replace `go()` and `transitionTo()` of `$state` methods with dummies:

```js
beforeEach( inject( function ( _$state_ ) {
        state = _$state_;
        spyOn( state, 'go' );
        spyOn( state, 'transitionTo' );
    } ) );
```

Comment: Amey this is correct.  How in the world did you come to know this?  Been working with angular for about 8 months now and  I'm totally new to Testing.  The deeper I go the more I find out I know nothing.  Do you have any recommendations to getting to your level?  In particular to e2e and unit testing?

Comment: @Amey is correct, ui-router-extras initializes the `$state` service which causes your default route to load and requests the template by URL.  See below for an alternate answer using `$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept()`.

Comment: `$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept()` is used to prevent requesting the "otherwise" configured state and doesn't solve the issue of the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate solution that doesn't nuke ui-router's `transitionTo` function.

---

First, the failing scenario can be reproduced by following these steps:

```
npm install yo generator-angular-fullstack;
yo angular-fullstack
```

Inject $state service by adding this line to client/app/app.js:

```
angular.module("yoAppName").run(function($state) {});
```

At this point, invoking `grunt karma` reports the `Unexpected request: GET app/main/main.html` because UI-Router is bootstrapped and tries to load the default route, which requests the route's template.

---

To address this, tell UI-Router to delay synchronizing the URL to the state, so we don't load the default route.  In the controller spec, add `$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();` to your test init code:

```
beforeEach(module('uiRouterExtrasKarmaBugApp'));
// Add the following line
beforeEach(module(function($urlRouterProvider) { $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(); }));
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Your test is failing because `ui-router-extras` is making an unexpected http GET request to `app/main/main.html` therefore test fails.

2) Actually there are a lot of suggestions in the issue that you linked to. I assume extra call is made to load the template for the default route, ie. `otherwise`. So overriding it might fix the problem:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function(){return false;});
}));
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this ... I'll update my answer with my changes but still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe you could take another look at it and see if it's a dummy error

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions actually... Right after the module declaration.

1. you can add:

   `beforeEach(module('stateMock'));`
2. or you can manually, defer the intercept:

   `beforeEach(module(function($urlRouterProvider) { $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(); }));`