# Why am I getting an Unexpected request error when testing an angular directive with no AJAX calls associated with it?

Tags: angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a (simple) directive that validates a text field to see if the inputted value is less than another controller's variable max value.

Here's my error:

```
IE 11.0.0 (Windows 7) Maximum value validator should be valid initially FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET app/layout/shell.html
    No more request expected
       at $httpBackend (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj/scripts/angular-mocks.js:1218:5)
       at sendReq (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj/scripts/angular.js:9462:9)
       at serverRequest (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj/scripts/angular.js:9179:9)
       at processQueue (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj/scripts/angular.js:12914:11)
       at Anonymous function (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj/scripts/angular.js:12930:27)
       at Scope.prototype.$eval (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj/scripts/angular.js:14123:9)
       at Scope.prototype.$digest (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj/scripts/angular.js:13939:15)
       at Anonymous function (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj.test/directiveTests.js:11:3)
       at invoke (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj/scripts/angular.js:4152:7)
       at workFn (C:/Projects/myProj/myProj/scripts/angular-mocks.js:2255:11)
```

So looking around this seems to be associated with not setting up an AJAX call. Except, as you can see below, my directive doesn't have any associated service calls at all on it. Plus, why the heck is it trying a GET request for the shell html file? Where did that come from?

I've only written a few tests so far as I'm just starting this project, but my other tests worked just fine. I'm running Karma if that might make a difference. I'm stumped though because my tests look like the example tests that are out there. If I debug through, everything seems great through the end of the test but I get the error after the test completes and the test fails with this error.

OK code time.

My directive:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');
app.directive('maxValue', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                var valid;
                if (value) {
                    var maxValue = scope.$eval(attrs.maxValue);
                    valid = parseInt(value, 10) <= maxValue;
                }
                return valid ? valid : undefined;
            });
        }
    };
});
})();
```

and my tests:

```
describe("Maximum value validator", function() {
var $scope, form;

beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    var element = angular.element('<form name="form"><input type="text" name="value" ng-model="value" max-value="maxValue" /></form>');
    $scope = $rootScope;
    $scope.value = 0;
    $scope.maxValue = 100;
    $compile(element)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
}));

it('should be valid initially', function () {
    expect($scope.form.value.$valid).toBe(true);
});

it('should be valid when value is the same as the max value', function() {
    $scope.form.value.$setViewValue('100');
    expect($scope.form.value.$valid).toBe(true);
});

it('should be invalid when the value is greater than the max value', function() {
    $scope.form.value.$setViewValue('101');
    expect($scope.form.value.$valid).toBe(false);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rball and I have came to the conclusion that the following fixed the "module not found" error:

```
var mod = angular.module('uiRouterNoop', []); 
mod.service('$state', function () { 
    return {} 
});
mod.service('$urlRouter', function () { 
    return {}; 
});
```

Then in the spec

```
beforeEach(module('uiRouterNoop'));
```

It is an important practice in angular to separate modules where need be. Most SPA's tie every module to the same one such as 'app'. But it is good to separate them for testing purposes such as these and can prevent dependency problems when testing due to complex mock scenarios.

Comment: Tried that, got: Module 'shell.html' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. What I suppose I don't understand is if app relies on it, which I don't see either, is why would my other tests work ok? Does it have something to do with $compile? That's the only difference between this test and the others.

Comment: Might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724956/ui-router-extras-breaks-my-unit-tests-with-unexpected-results-error except I don't have ui-router-extras, just ui-router... I tried that answer and it didn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/212 This seemed to fix it. Particularly: var mod = angular.module('uiRouterNoop', []);
mod.service('$state', function () { return {} });
mod.service('$urlRouter', function () { return {} }); and then in the test beforeEach(module('uiRouterNoop')); If you want to edit your answer I'll give you the points as you were the only one to respond :)

Comment: Cheers! This is most likely due to some weird dependency issue, but it is best practice to separate modules. If this module was the one giving you issues, you can also use the $provide to provide it instead. It'd be something like module('app', ['$provide', function ($provide) { $provide.value('uiRouterNoop', {}); }];  Might be good to try in the long run if you see this problem again in your app.