# Angular 1.5.x unit tests fail because they request $route default templateUrls

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I've recently updated an app to Angular 1.5.x and now unit tests are failing because the templateUrl for the default route is trying to be fetched on $digest();

I've been trying to find a difference in expected behaviour in the Angular changelog but haven't been able to track it down.

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET views/dashboard.html
No more request expected in .../app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js (line 1404)
$httpBackend@.../app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1404:90
sendReq@.../app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11293:21
serverRequest@.../app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11003:23
processQueue@.../app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15627:30
.../app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15643:39
$eval@.../app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16895:28
$digest@.../app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16711:36
.../test/spec/controllers/dashboard.js:96:29
```

What is the cause of this and how can it be fixed? Happy to supply more examples if necessary. The tests are written using Jasmine and are exectured by Karma.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a scope and apply/digest is called, digest by default will start traversing changes on rootscope, if you are using $state the default state will be resolved on the first digest loading an unexpected template.

If you don't need to test for state change i suggest using defer intercept method

```
beforeEach(module(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
     $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
}));
```

Or as suggested in this post if you wish to spy on state changes [UI Router Extras breaks my unit tests with unexpected results error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724956/ui-router-extras-breaks-my-unit-tests-with-unexpected-results-error)

```
beforeEach( inject( function ( _$state_ ) {
    state = _$state_;
    spyOn( state, 'go' );
    spyOn( state, 'transitionTo' );
} ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this new behaviour? The tests are identical to what they were when we were running 1.4.x, I'm still trying to understand why this started to fail now.